# How to install Ubuntu in Windows 7 ?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7

when i installed Ubuntu in windows 7,it's generate such error.
show this image

[image: ERROR]

Comment: It simply asks you to use another username as "admin" has already been reserved for use by common system packages to avoid a serious security loophole. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=450954

Comment: Try VirtualBox instead. Running ubuntu this way is very slow. Virtualbox adds you the snapshot feature, it's quite cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"admin" is a reserved username on some Ubuntu versions( it's a bug ). Try something else like *yourname*.
More Details: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=450954

Answer (score 1):

Use latest Ubantu 11.10 using wubi.

Here is the link

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

While installing choose latest version.

Meantime Admin is root user, you cannot use this.. If you want to enable root user you have to enable this after installing Linux from config file.

Comment: +1 for noticing that the OP was attempting to install a really old version.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have use a reserved word. So try any other name just like admin1 or your name instead of admin.